# How to search base64encoded string in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, base64

I have search functionality using keywords and the keyword stored in base64encoded string.
How can i search that keyword?

example: I entered  `he` in textbox to search ... and i have multiple values in column like

```
he - aGU=

hea - aGVh
```

different substring have different base64encode string

```
bXkgaGVhbHRo  - my Health

aGVhbHRoIGlzIGdvb2Q= - health is good
```

I have used LIKE in query

```
SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE texting LIKE '%aGU=%'
```

I have tried

```
TO_BASE64(str) and FROM_BASE64() but it works on 5.6.1 and i have version 5.0.7
```

How is it possible?

Comment: You have to decode that again in order to search in it.

Comment: it works when full word but not if i enter he at place of health and so on

Comment: You have to encode your input value first and apply that keyword in like parameter

Comment: You have to do something like this: `SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE decode(texting) LIKE '%Health%'`

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding data when you store it in your database anyway? What benefit do you get from that? You've clearly already found some of the drawbacks

Comment: that the order to do it and store it in database like this

Answer (score 1):

**In MySQL 5.6.1.**

Use `TO_BASE64(str)` and `FROM_BASE64()`

See mysql doc:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_to-base64

**ALTERNATIVE MYSQL FUNCTION**

```
delimiter |

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS base64_data |
CREATE TABLE base64_data (c CHAR(1) BINARY, val TINYINT) |
INSERT INTO base64_data VALUES 
    ('A',0), ('B',1), ('C',2), ('D',3), ('E',4), ('F',5), ('G',6), ('H',7), ('I',8), ('J',9),
    ('K',10), ('L',11), ('M',12), ('N',13), ('O',14), ('P',15), ('Q',16), ('R',17), ('S',18), ('T',19),
    ('U',20), ('V',21), ('W',22), ('X',23), ('Y',24), ('Z',25), ('a',26), ('b',27), ('c',28), ('d',29),
    ('e',30), ('f',31), ('g',32), ('h',33), ('i',34), ('j',35), ('k',36), ('l',37), ('m',38), ('n',39),
    ('o',40), ('p',41), ('q',42), ('r',43), ('s',44), ('t',45), ('u',46), ('v',47), ('w',48), ('x',49),
    ('y',50), ('z',51), ('0',52), ('1',53), ('2',54), ('3',55), ('4',56), ('5',57), ('6',58), ('7',59),
    ('8',60), ('9',61), ('+',62), ('/',63), ('=',0) |


DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS BASE64_DECODE |
CREATE FUNCTION BASE64_DECODE (input BLOB)
    RETURNS BLOB
    CONTAINS SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE ret BLOB DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT 0;

    IF input IS NULL THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

each_block:
    WHILE NOT done DO BEGIN
        DECLARE accum_value BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE in_count TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE out_count TINYINT DEFAULT 3;

each_input_char:
        WHILE in_count < 4 DO BEGIN
            DECLARE first_char CHAR(1);

            IF LENGTH(input) = 0 THEN
                RETURN ret;
            END IF;

            SET first_char = SUBSTRING(input,1,1);
            SET input = SUBSTRING(input,2);

            BEGIN
                DECLARE tempval TINYINT UNSIGNED;
                DECLARE error TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE base64_getval CURSOR FOR SELECT val FROM base64_data WHERE c = first_char;
                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET error = 1;

                OPEN base64_getval;
                FETCH base64_getval INTO tempval;
                CLOSE base64_getval;

                IF error THEN
                    ITERATE each_input_char;
                END IF;

                SET accum_value = (accum_value << 6) + tempval;
            END;

            SET in_count = in_count + 1;

            IF first_char = '=' THEN
                SET done = 1;
                SET out_count = out_count - 1;
            END IF;
        END; END WHILE;

        -- We've now accumulated 24 bits; deaccumulate into bytes

        -- We have to work from the left, so use the third byte position and shift left
        WHILE out_count > 0 DO BEGIN
            SET ret = CONCAT(ret,CHAR((accum_value & 0xff0000) >> 16));
            SET out_count = out_count - 1;
            SET accum_value = (accum_value << 8) & 0xffffff;
        END; END WHILE;

    END; END WHILE;

    RETURN ret;
END |

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS BASE64_ENCODE |
CREATE FUNCTION BASE64_ENCODE (input BLOB)
    RETURNS BLOB
    CONTAINS SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE ret BLOB DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT 0;

    IF input IS NULL THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

each_block:
    WHILE NOT done DO BEGIN
        DECLARE accum_value BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE in_count TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE out_count TINYINT;

each_input_char:
        WHILE in_count < 3 DO BEGIN
            DECLARE first_char CHAR(1);

            IF LENGTH(input) = 0 THEN
                SET done = 1;
                SET accum_value = accum_value << (8 * (3 - in_count));
                LEAVE each_input_char;
            END IF;

            SET first_char = SUBSTRING(input,1,1);
            SET input = SUBSTRING(input,2);

            SET accum_value = (accum_value << 8) + ASCII(first_char);

            SET in_count = in_count + 1;
        END; END WHILE;

        -- We've now accumulated 24 bits; deaccumulate into base64 characters

        -- We have to work from the left, so use the third byte position and shift left
        CASE
            WHEN in_count = 3 THEN SET out_count = 4;
            WHEN in_count = 2 THEN SET out_count = 3;
            WHEN in_count = 1 THEN SET out_count = 2;
            ELSE RETURN ret;
        END CASE;

        WHILE out_count > 0 DO BEGIN
            BEGIN
                DECLARE out_char CHAR(1);
                DECLARE base64_getval CURSOR FOR SELECT c FROM base64_data WHERE val = (accum_value >> 18);

                OPEN base64_getval;
                FETCH base64_getval INTO out_char;
                CLOSE base64_getval;

                SET ret = CONCAT(ret,out_char);
                SET out_count = out_count - 1;
                SET accum_value = accum_value << 6 & 0xffffff;
            END;
        END; END WHILE;

        CASE
            WHEN in_count = 2 THEN SET ret = CONCAT(ret,'=');
            WHEN in_count = 1 THEN SET ret = CONCAT(ret,'==');
            ELSE BEGIN END;
        END CASE;

    END; END WHILE;

    RETURN ret;
END |
```

from

- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,404800,404800
- http://wi-fizzle.com/downloads/base64.sql

Comment: it returns value blob

Comment: phpmyadmin returns a blob? what about php results?